# Using unique_ptr and shared_ptr with function parameters in C++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm calling Windows functions like GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl that dynamically allocate memory (arrays) on my behalf whose memory must be freed with a call to LocalFree.

```
ULONG EntryCount;
EXPLICIT_ACCESS* pItem = nullptr;
ULONG EntryCount;
status = GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl(pACL, &EntryCount, &pItem);
...
...
LocalFree(pItem);
```

Can I declare pItem to be an instance of std::shared_ptr and still have              GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl allocate it for me?

How?

Comment: No.  You cannot.  Also, unique_ptr would be the appropriate smart pointer type if you could somehow do this.  You could put it into a unique_ptr afterwards if you wanted, however, but you'd need a custom Deleter for it to call LocalFree instead of delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a *custom deleter* so that `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` know the special way to delete the memory. Something like this:

```
struct explicit_access_deleter
{
    void operator()(EXPLICIT_ACCESS* pItem) const
    {
        if(pItem)
            LocalFree(pItem);
    }
};
```

Then you can provide *maker functions* to call the allocation function and use your special deleter:

```
std::unique_ptr<EXPLICIT_ACCESS, explicit_access_deleter>
    make_explicit_access_unique_ptr(ULONG EntryCount)
{
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS* pItem = nullptr;
    int status = GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl(pACL, &EntryCount, &pItem);
    // do some error checking here ...
    return std::unique_ptr<EXPLICIT_ACCESS, explicit_access_deleter>(pItem);
}

std::shared_ptr<EXPLICIT_ACCESS>
    make_explicit_access_shared_ptr(ULONG EntryCount)
{
    return make_explicit_access_unique_ptr(EntryCount);
}
```

Comment: DRY.   Have the shared version use the unique one.  shared_ptr even has a constructor that takes a unique_ptr: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping avoid writing a lot of wrapper functions... Some other non-standard smart pointer libraries implement address_of and pointer_to functions for classes similar to unique_ptr that allow you to avoid writing wrappers.